# How to initiate a debug session from a random request in Eclipse PDT with XDebug?

Tags: eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I use the combination of Eclipse PDT and XDebug very successfully to develop and debug my applications. So thanks to their creators, and if you haven't tried this combination, I strongly suggest you do.

The only thing bugging me is, that I couldn't find a way to start a debug session by requesting a random script right in my browser. I always have to start the session in Eclipse on one of my scripts and debug configurations.

I have minimized the pain by adding a "debug.php" to my project that contains only

```
<?php 
// you can debug any request now
```

but still I have to finish this script and then do the request to whatever I really want to debug.

Is there a way to create a debug configuration that is not bound to a specific script but just tells PDT to start listening for requests from XDebug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to preferences panel and select php->debug->installed debuggers and click on xdebug then click on configure. There should be an option to allow incoming connections. Select that and you can launch remote debug sessions from firefox with the xdebug extension

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you! The firefox extension seems to have vanished, but adding ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP to my request manually isn't that much work.

Comment: Ah btw for everybody trying this now, the option is called "Accept remote session (JIT)".